# Why does the downvote still persist even after I removed my downvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, migration

I posted an answer to [Why is any number divided by 0 is infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1399099/); it was rather too short, I confess [but correct], & this might prompted someone to downvote me; my rep got decreased by 2. Then I thought, why to waste my rep?? I deleted my answer.

Then I saw, it was migrated to MSE. I thought to extend my answer & explain OP elaborately. The answer was accepted & I got +25. But then I noticed my PSE rep still showed a decrease of 2! I checked my profile & saw it was the same downvote to the answer of the same question I deleted. I don't know why it is so:( What is the logic for continuing the downvote to a **deleted** answer? Can anyone explain why it happened? Is there any to avert it?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86684/209806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [original phys.SE thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200680/2451) still exists for some overlap period.

1. If the migration is successful, the original physics thread will eventually be deleted, with corresponding changes in the Phys.SE reputation for the users involved.
2. If the migration is rejected, the original physics thread will remain, thereby keeping its Phys.SE reputation scores.

In the present case, the migration will likely be rejected by Math.SE due to multiple duplicates. It will then turn into a closed thread on Phys.SE.

Comment: +1;But, sir, before the quo was migrated, as it showed, I already deleted:(

Comment: Your answer on Phys.SE is currently _not_ deleted, so if you tried to delete it, you did not succeed. Perhaps your attempt was interrupted by the migration?

Comment: Okay, now it sounds pretty ghastly:| Is there any way to have an exorcism??

Comment: When it turns back to PSE as a closed thread, can I delete then, as you said, my undeleted answer??

Comment: Yes. (11 more to go...)

Comment: **Correction Aug 19th:** It seems a migrated post _closed as duplicate_ doesn't invalidate the migration. So the original Phys.SE  thread is going to be deleted in the near future.

Comment: Observation for later: Btw, it is a bit strange that one answer (at -1, not locked) was not deleted immediately, while the other answer (also at -1, locked) got deleted immediately. It seems they should receive the same treatment. Speculates it might have to do with disputed flags or similar issues.

Comment: **Update Sep 19th:**  Original Phys.SE thread is now deleted.